# How to make field read only in infopath

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I need to make the field `Date` read only :

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click on `Date` field
2. Click *Tex Box Propetries*
3. Click on *Display* tab
4. Check *Read-only*
5. Click *OK*

This is for text box

---

**EDIT**

This is for Date and DateAndTime

1. Right click on `Date` field
2. *Rules > Manage rules*
3. New Rule - *Formatting*
4. Condition `Date` *is blank/is not blank*
5. *Disable this control*

:)

Comment: it's available for text box and not for data field. I try it

Comment: Great, thank You Marko!

Answer (score 0):

you can make it read only in the properties of that field or you can create a rule that will set the value and disable the control.